# Configure Pojo with Map attribute doesnt' generate "additionalProperties" using Swagger 1.5

Tags: java, json, hashmap, apache-camel, swagger

I have implemented some endpoints using Spring Boot and Apache Camel and I'm trying to document them with camel-swagger-java and generating a client library with swagger-codegen later on. The issue is that one of the attributes of my model is a HashMap and I'm trying to configure the pojo in a way that swagger could generate the **additionalProperty** but no luck so far.

```
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public class TaskDataResultResponse {

        private String testing;

        @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
        @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "Map[String,String]")
        private Map<String, String> properties;

        @JsonAnyGetter
        public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
            return properties;
        }

        @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
        @JsonAnySetter
        public void setProperties(String name, String value) {
            properties.put(name, value);
        }

        public String getTesting() {
            return testing;
        }

        public void setTesting(String testing) {
            this.testing = testing;
        }
    }
```

I've tried everyting: Adding the JsonAnySetter and Getter annotations, Adding the ApiModelProperty swagger anotation, even extend the class from HashMap instead of having a HashMap attribute but nothing seems to work:

[image: Swagger schema with no "additionalProperties" in it]

I've read a lot in swagger-core github repo, in stack overflow and searching the web and so far nothing. I know lots of stuff of how configure a swagger schema file by adding this additional property but my goal is to generate that automatically from a pojo.

I'm using the latest Spring Boot (2.4.3, but I also tested with previous versions as well) and camel-swagger-java 3.7.3 (but also tested wth 2.25.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of investigation I found the issue in my code: I was mixing up annotations. After removing *ApiModelProperty*, *JsonAnyGetter* and *setter* annotations the schema file finally got generated correctly.

Also, related to this issue, I found a way to implement the same logic but with a list of hashmaps, because i also needed the *additionalProperties* attribute to be generated in the swagger schema for elements on a list.

[image: List of Hashmaps in an attribute]

[image: Swagger scheme with additionalProperties on a list]

Finally I have generated a client (using swagger codegen) and the information is being unmarshalled correctly, for both *formdata* and *datagridData* attributes.